# Set different priority to android manifest attribute when merged

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I'm working on an app with 3 different manifests ( different modules).

```
          Product2(Build variant)         Product1(Build variant)
                    |                               |
                    |                               |
                     \                             /
                      \                           /
                       \                         /
                     Core Application logic (Main manifest)
```

Every time I build the project all tags in the core `<manifest>` tag are being overridden by the build variants.(This is the normal behavior as for official doc and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#appendix_merge_policies)).

How do I set specific attribute (or all the  tag) to have higher priority and ignore the [default priority structure](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_priorities)?